# yum lockfile is held by another user

Tags: yum, amazon-ec2, aws, ansible, amazon-linux

`Amazon Linux 2` instances are operated upon by an Ansible Playbook which performs multiple `yum` tasks one after the other.

> **What specific changes need to be made to the syntax below in order for the successive `yum` tasks to run without stopping due to process conflicts?**

Currently, the second `yum` task below is failing because Ansible does not know how to handle hearing that the preceding `yum` task has not yet let go of the `yum` `lockfile`.

Here is the current error message that files when the second `yum` task below is called:

```
TASK [remove any previous versions of specific stuff] ************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.1.0.232]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "yum lockfile is held by another process"}
```

The two successive `yum` tasks are currently written as follows:

```
 - name: Perform yum update of all packages
   yum:
     name: '*'
     state: latest

 - name: remove any previous versions of specific stuff
   yum:
     name: thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5, thing6
     state: absent
```

I imagine the solution is just to add something telling Ansible to wait until the first task's `yum` lock has been released.  But what syntax should be used for this?

Comment: I have never encountered such an issue with ansible. Are your sure a process refreshing yum/rpm db (not related to your ansible run) is not launched automagically on your host right after a change has been made ? If you really need to cope with this, the [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) module could help (see options `path` and `state`).

Comment: I would confirm that the yum lockfile is actually held by the previous Ansible task. Do you have PackageKit or another system tool installed? It may be validating system changes after the first task completes but before the second begins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your running into this issue using Ansible 2.8, it want's to blow up now when running YUM Package installs. Easy work around to this is to set the `lock_timeout` var to 100 + as the default is set to 0.

```
- name: Install yum utils
  yum:
    name:
    - yum-utils
    - "@Development tools"
    lock_timeout: 180
```

Unfortunately the trouble with this is that when you have a lot of Ansible tasks that install YUM Packages you need to go add this var to every single task. I've been looking for a way to set this globally some how but no joy. Hope that helps!

Links:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/57189
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html

Comment: Thank you and +1 for seeming to answer my question.  I am marking this as answered before the problem does not seem to appear when I re-run the playbook after a few strategically placed additions of `lock_timeout: 180`.  If the problem re-appears with repeated runs of the playbook, I will revisit here.  Welcome to the site.